# Dropdown Selection for a table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to create a dropdown selector for a table.  It is not selecting and I am still rather new to javascript.

Here is the snippet I was working on.

```js
$('#vehicleSelect').change( function(){
  var selection = $(this).val();
  var dataset = $('#vehicleTable tbody').find('tr');
  
  dataset.each(function(index) {
    item = $(this);
    item.hide();
    
    var firstTd = item.find('td:first-child');
    var text = firstTd.text();
    if text == selection {
        item.show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='vehicleSelect'>
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
   <option value='SPARC'>SPARC</option>
   <option value='CIO_SP3_SB'>CIO_SP3_SB</option>
   <option value='CIO_SP3'>CIO_SP3</option>
   <option value='T4NG'>T4NG</option>
</select>

<table id='vehicleTable'>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Contract Type</th>
         <th>Contract Number</th>
         <th>Contract Holder</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>SPARC</td>
          <td>Conract1</td>
          <td>Company1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>CIO_SP3_SB</td>
         <td>Conract2</td>
         <td>Company2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>T4NG</td>
         <td>Conract3</td>
         <td>Company3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>CIO_SP3</td>
          <td>Conract4</td>
          <td>Company4</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to reach?

Comment: Well the error message should help?

Comment: Your drop down change event no firing or what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be nothing wrong in the code except no `()` in the if-condition.

```
if (text == selection) 
{
    item.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Varun's answer says the main problem comes from the parentheses `()`, but you could also shorten this action, so you don't need to loop like the sample below shows using `contains()` selector :

```
$('#vehicleSelect').change(function() {
  $('#vehicleTable tbody tr')
    .hide()
    .find('td:first-child:contains("' + $(this).val() + '")')
    .parent()
    .show();
});
```

```js
$('#vehicleSelect').change(function() {
  $('#vehicleTable tbody tr')
    .hide()
    .find('td:first-child:contains("' + $(this).val() + '")')
    .parent()
    .show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='vehicleSelect'>
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
   <option value='SPARC'>SPARC</option>
   <option value='CIO_SP3_SB'>CIO_SP3_SB</option>
   <option value='CIO_SP3'>CIO_SP3</option>
   <option value='T4NG'>T4NG</option>
</select>

<table id='vehicleTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Contract Type</th>
      <th>Contract Number</th>
      <th>Contract Holder</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>SPARC</td>
      <td>Conract1</td>
      <td>Company1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO_SP3_SB</td>
      <td>Conract2</td>
      <td>Company2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T4NG</td>
      <td>Conract3</td>
      <td>Company3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO_SP3</td>
      <td>Conract4</td>
      <td>Company4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or also using `filter()` :

```
$('#vehicleSelect').change(function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();

  $('#vehicleTable tbody tr')
    .hide()
    .find('td:first-child')
    .filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === selected; })
    .parent()
    .show();
});
```

```js
$('#vehicleSelect').change(function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();

  $('#vehicleTable tbody tr')
    .hide()
    .find('td:first-child')
    .filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === selected; })
    .parent()
    .show();
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='vehicleSelect'>
   <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
   <option value='SPARC'>SPARC</option>
   <option value='CIO_SP3_SB'>CIO_SP3_SB</option>
   <option value='CIO_SP3'>CIO_SP3</option>
   <option value='T4NG'>T4NG</option>
</select>

<table id='vehicleTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Contract Type</th>
      <th>Contract Number</th>
      <th>Contract Holder</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>SPARC</td>
      <td>Conract1</td>
      <td>Company1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO_SP3_SB</td>
      <td>Conract2</td>
      <td>Company2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T4NG</td>
      <td>Conract3</td>
      <td>Company3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CIO_SP3</td>
      <td>Conract4</td>
      <td>Company4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does, thanks for putting in some effort to clean my code. Also, how do I get the table to default with no values shown when the page loads?  Right now if I want the all to be hidden, I have to select and item, then select "Please Select"

Comment: Glad I could helps bro, you've just to set the slected item by default like `<option value="" selected>Please Select</option>` then to add `.change();` at the end of the event (check my update in the second snippet).